# Is it okay to send a connection invitation on LinkedIn to an academic event director?

Tags: conference, networking, linkedin

As a just graduated student, I have submitted my contribution proposal for an academic event and the organising committee has accepted it.
Despite I have still met none of the above mentioned committee members, would it be fine to already send a connection invitation on LinkedIn to most of them (in particular to the event director)? If yes, would it be better to include also a custom message into the invitation request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely to cause harm for you to send the invitation.  It is likely to be ignored.

Comment: Since my connection invitation “is likely to be ignored”, are there some hints you suggest in order to minimise the probability that the invitation is ignored? For instance, would it be better to send it after an in person meeting during the event?

Comment: No hints.  In my experience academics don't care about linkedin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think totally appropriate. A lot of academics use Linked In to expand their networks. Some can be a bit precious about 'curating' their connections but most are all about expanding their networks.